Google Drive API in svelte - How to make user don't have to re-signIn after reload the page
Hey I'm just wondering how can i use google drive api to let user don't have to re-sign in the account to make request with google drie api in my svelte project
For now after i signIn everything works well I can upload, read, update file, but after i refresh the page i can't do any of them, I know there is refreshToken for this, but I can't use it(return undefined)
AI told me to place something like:
await gapi.auth2.setAuthInstance().setOptions({
      access_type: 'offline'
});
//or
await gapi.client.setAccessToken('offline');

in initializeGapiClient() or login() but the browser console shows they are not defined.
Here are some of my code:
Import the api with <svelte:head> which include
<svelte:head>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
</svelte:head>

I load the api when page load
$: onMount(() => {
    gapiLoaded();
    gisLoaded();
});

the code of relative function up there
let gapiInited = false;
let gisInited = false;
const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'];
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
// ... CLIENT_ID CLIENT_SECRET API_KEY 
function gapiLoaded() {
    gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
}

async function initializeGapiClient() {
    await gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS
    });
    gapiInited = true;
}

    function gisLoaded() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: ''
    });
    gisInited = true;
}


when user signIn
function SignIn() {
    tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
        if (resp.error !== undefined) {
              throw resp;
        }

        const tokens = await gapi.auth.getToken();
        const accessToken = tokens.access_token;
        const refreshToken = tokens.refresh_token; // <- get undefined

        localStorage.setItem('token', accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refreshToken);  // <- get undefined

        authed = true;
        console.log('Sign-in Successful');
    };

    if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
    } else {
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' });
    }
}

upload file
function upload() {
    if (uploadData != null) {
        const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(uploadData)], { type: 'application/json'});
        const parentFolder = localStorage.getItem('parent_folder');
        let fileName = 'smoothword-data'; // set file metadata
        let metadata = {
            name: fileName + '.json',
            mimeType: 'application/json',
            parents: [parentFolder]
        };

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(
            'metadata',
            new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' })
        );
        formData.append('file', blob);
        fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            }),
            body: formData
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                localStorage.setItem('file_id', response.id);
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (value) {
                console.log(value);
            });
    }
}

